# How to upload a file against a custom/standard object record?

Tags: attachment, files, configuration

We have been using Attachment and we have just started to explore Files so bear with me if this question is silly.

I am aware that I can upload files using the "Files" tab but I would like to upload a PDF file only for a specific custom/standard record..not just a general upload.

Also do we have to resort to salesforce dev to do that (ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink creation).

Is there a OOTB way to just upload a "File" pdf file  against a custom/standard object record (like how we have for Attachment) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add files related list on page layout of an object and upload files like you do on attachment.

You can review [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_related_list_setup.htm&type=5) help article for more

It would be something like this - for example in an account here
[image]